# registration with django social linked them up

Tags: django

I want a registration system that allows email conformations with all normal registration goodies. I will be using [userena](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena), this seems perfect.

Next, I need to allow users to link  with their twitter accounts or to sign with their twitter account if they want.

So what are my options? I was looking at using [django social](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth). can the two be linked? or is there a better solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at django-allauth over at http://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth -- it offers "all normal registration goodies" together with Twitter signin (and lots of others), all out of the box, with flows that just work.

Whether or not it is the better solution I will leave up to you to decide.

(Note: even though I am the author of allauth this answer is meant to be honestly helpful and is not to be regarded as a shameless form of self promotion)